# Install ggplot2 on opensuse 11.4

Tags: r, ggplot2, opensuse

I'm trying to install ggplot2, however I get the following error:

> trying URL
>   'http://cran.skazkaforyou.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_0.8.9.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2074749 bytes (2.0 Mb) opened
>   URL
>   ================================================== downloaded 2.0 Mb
>
> * installing *source* package ‘plyr’ ...
>
> ** libs
>
> sh: make: command not found
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘plyr’
>
> * removing
>   ‘/home/jayron/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.12/plyr’
>
> * installing *source* package ‘digest’ ...
>
> ** libs sh: make: command not found
>
> sh: make: command not found ERROR: compilation failed for package
>   ‘colorspace’
>
> ERROR: dependencies ‘reshape’, ‘plyr’, ‘digest’, ‘colorspace’ are not
>   available for package ‘ggplot2’
>   * removing ‘/home/jayron/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.12/ggplot2’
>
> The downloaded packages are in
>           ‘/tmp/Rtmp0Sgoxp/downloaded_packages’

any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Thank you guys, I got it!...at last =)

Comment: I am rather surprised this method works for Ageu. The message clearly indicate missing development tools, which is unrelated to repos URL: `make: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

You need development packages. Unless someone has packaged a recent Ggplot2 for opensuse, you will need to install these using (I think) zypper. The error message says you do not have 'make' on your system. It is likely that there will be more.

Answer (score 0):

You need development packages. Until someone has packaged a recent ggplot2 for opensuse, which has not yet happened yet today (Jan 2014), you will need to be root to install these using zypper:

```
# zypper install r-base-devel
```

This package exists since opensuse 11.3.

The error message says you do not have 'make' on your system. If you only install 'make', it is likely that there will be more similiar errors. Thus you need to install all development tools needed for ggplot2. This can be done by root with

```
# zypper install -t pattern devel_C_C++
```