# R packages in openSUSE 13.1

Tags: r, gcc, opensuse

This issue was reported on stack overflow [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041941/install-ggplot2-on-opensuse-11-4) but no matter what I do I still get the same thing. Whenever I try to install any R package i get the following:

```
install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")
Installing package into ‘/home/budjajojo/R_packages’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Hmisc_3.13-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 587751 bytes (573 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 573 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘Hmisc’ ...
** package ‘Hmisc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Hmisc’
* removing ‘/home/budjajojo/R_packages/Hmisc’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp6fA61h/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org") :
  installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am using the new openSUSE 13.1. and R version 3.0.2. that I have installed from [R-patched](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/suse/README.html) repositories.

Besides the solution from the similar post I have tried the following:

- changing the library path to be in my home folder (maybe privileges
  issue)
- installing and updating the gcc compiler (both gcc++ and gfortran)
- changing between versions of the gcc with update-alternatives (tried
  the gcc3 version)
- tried everything as a superuser

Off course none of the above solutions worked. I think it is gcc issue (ver. 4.8.1) but I`m not sure what can be done.

Comment: What about running R as sudo?

Comment: Yes yes I tried that also...but in the meantime I managed to solve the problem. The issue was with R-devel version and it being shifted away from make. I have reinstalled both R (as R-patched) and make, so it just worked after that. I feel dull about posting this huge question for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 9):

openSUSE does not come with `make` installed by default. You have to install it with Yast or type in terminal:

```
sudo zypper install make
```

Usually, to be sure everything works fine with R on openSUSE, namely packages that depend on `rgl`, I install all these packages:

```
sudo zypper install libpng12-devel xorg-x11-libs freeglut-devel gcc gcc-fortran gcc-c++ make r-base r-base-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

On Open Suse:

```
zypper search --type pattern devel
```

That command lists group of packages related.
Install if needed.

Thanks!